# Component does re-render even after I called setState?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following react-native program:

```
class offerDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        phone: null,
        logo: null,
        instagram: null
    };
    const { name } = this.props.doc.data();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('companies').doc(name);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    let docObject = null;
    this.ref.get().then(doc => {
      let docObject = doc.data();
      console.log(docObject); -----------------------------1
      });
      this.setState(
        docObject

      );
      console.log(this.state); --------------------------------2
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);--------------------3
...
```

......

I have 3 instances where I print to the console. Only in instance number 1 does it print non null values, however, in instance 2 and 3 it prints null values. Why is instance 2 printing null if it is called right after setState?

Can it be that its not setting the state correctly and why?

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` in React is asynchronous.

From the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) (3rd paragraph):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback...

If you want to access the state once it has been updated, you can add a callback like so:

```
this.setState({ docObject }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.docObject);
});
```

Comment: What if I want to access it from inside the render method? As you see its returning null in location 3. That's where I really need it?

Comment: You would have to perform some check, `if (this.state.docObject) { // loaded } else { // still null }`.